# understanding mathematical inequality.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm tyring to understand the proof for the the below by induction.

Show that $\ 2^n > n^2$ wherever n is a positive integer grater than 4.

since $k>4$

$$ 2^{k+1} = 2. 2^k > k^2 + k^2 $$

I'm unable to get convinced logically of the above without putting in some values ?
Is it possible to prove above without putting in some values or interpreting thorugh plots ?

Comment: It holds by the induction hypothesis. Now it remains to show that $2k^2\geq  (k+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$2^k > k^2\tag{1}$$

Just multiply it by $2$.

Answer (score 2):

we assume that $$2^k>k^2$$ (I) for $k>4$ we have to prove that $$2^{k+1}>(k+1)^2$$
multiplying (I) by $2$ we get
$$2^{k+1}>2k^2$$ now we have $$2k^2>(k+1)^2$$ this is true since we have for $k>4$ $$k^2-2k-1>0$$